# Placing An image next a centered table

Tags: html, css

This may be a "ReWashed" Question but i am having difficulties placing an image next to a table that has been centered the below code is the snippet i am stuck with.

```html
<img src="FS.png" class="abcdef" width="124" height="166" style="float:right;position: relative"/>
            <div align="center">
                  
              <table width="576" border="1">
                <tr>
            <td width="348">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="212">&nbsp;</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        </div>
```

the image is being placed on the far right of the screen the table is centered and i need the image to be placed next to the center of the table.

Comment: Try float and then readjust the width of the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div#tab{width:580px; float:left;}
div#pix{width:150px; float:right;}

body{width:730px;
  margin:0 auto;}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="tab">

  <table width="576" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td width="348">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="212">&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
<div id="pix">
  <img src="FS.png" class="abcdef" width="124" height="166" float="right" position="relative"/>
</div>
  </body>
```

Comment: thank you i was thinking of doing that.. but the table will be populated by PHP hopefully that wont affect its structure.